# ASP.NET MVC: Adding selected CSS class to ActionLink if url matches current url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is the simplest way of adding a selected css class to an ActionLink if the url of the action link matches the page being displayed?

Thanks!

Comment: The discussion with this question might help with your decision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964520/how-would-you-show-which-tab-is-selected-on-a-website-built-from-a-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard question, at first glance the only valid answer that comes to my minds is "it depends". Do you mean simple as in simple to code or simple to understand or simple to...

It can be done using jquery and window.location.pathname stripping out and applying class based on controller and/or action (usually .substr(1 and/or 2)).

It can be done using MenuModel with SelectedItem pointer, adding class based on it.
It can be done using MenuItem[] with property selected, adding class based on it.

It can probably be done in various additional ways (ViewBag springs to mind). 
Each consisting of two steps:
1. Save/calculate selected menu item
2. Set class based on this.

As for what is more simple, I think it depends on your preferences and the requirements on the site. The javascript approach might not be the best if you are to support non-javascript users ^^

Rant out

Comment: I went with an approach similar to the model method. I ended up passing the menu partial view a view model item which specified the section of the site we were in. I then set the css class in the menu accordingly. In other areas I used a little JS and window.location to highlight the correct link. I don't mind non JS users not getting a menu highlight :)

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick

```
var currentUrl = location.pathname; //spits out something like 'Home/About'

$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == currentUrl) {
        $(this).addClass('yourClassName');
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not handle mvc links with ids in them or query strings.

Comment: @NickLarsen: True, I didn't think about that. But I did some testing, and with an action link like this `Html.ActionLink("Link", "Action", "Controller", new { id = 123 }, null)` it still works. Both the jQuery `attr('href')` and `location.pathname` calls returned 'Controller/Action/Id'. I still wanna do some more testing using a query string, e.g. `Controller/Action?id=123`

Comment: @tobias86 : did you do more testing ? Is there cases that are an issue for this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

We match the current URL against a regex for each nav option and set it selected if there is a match.

Comment: I like this idea...instead of a direct url comparison, a regex match will work much better

Answer (score 0):

add a property like LinkCssNaame to your view model and have the controller set it on the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension method.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkWithSelection(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        const string action = "action";
        const string controller = "controller";
        const string selected = "selected";
        var routeValues = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
        var linkMatchesRoute = routeValues.ContainsKey(action) && routeValues.ContainsKey(controller) &&
                               actionName.Equals(routeValues[action]) && controllerName.Equals(routeValues[controller]);
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, null, linkMatchesRoute ? new { @class = selected } : null);
    }
```